# MVC - Using Windows Authentication and inject Roles without doing it per request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, roles

The "dream" is to use WindowsAuthentication for an intranet site. However, we need to hit a 3rd party service to determine if the user has "permission" to use the site, thus "Roles". I have seen many examples that show how to add roles to the identity but they are all on "per request" basis. I don't want to do that. I would like for the user to hit the site once, I determine if the user has the permission, and add the role to the identity. The identity (with the role) sticks around for the session. I also don't want to have to cache users and their permissions. Is this doable or am I missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: This is a good question... having only started working with MVC earlier this year, I was also struck with curiosity when I discovered that our app was authenticating users on every request they made.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to write your own Authentication and put caching in the middle. It is really easy to do as I have two methods of doing it.

### Pre ASP.NET MVC 5

http://tech.pro/tutorial/1216/implementing-custom-authentication-for-aspnet

### ASP.NET MVC 5+ OWIN

http://www.khalidabuhakmeh.com/asp-net-mvc-5-authentication-breakdown-part-deux

My posts describe the basics of writing your own authentication, but it is pretty easy to integrate a third party service once you understand the basics. Hope that helps :)